# Gparted won't resize Ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have 2 partitions, 1 for boot and 1 for Ubuntu. I'm trying to shrink the Ubuntu partition to create one for Win11. But Gparted won't let me: every time I assign a new value to the size of the partition the program automatically changes it back to it's original size.

[image]

There are many questions similar to this one, but all I found had many partitions and the problem was they were trying to shrink a partition that was not the Ubuntu one.

Comment: In the questions you say you looked at I'm sure many of them mentioned that you can't do it from a running system, that the usual way is to do it from a live session.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Didn't come across one of those, thanks

Comment: As the answers to many similar questions say, you cannot operate on a locked partition. The key icons indicate that both partitions are locked. Boot to a live USB and you can do it. But backup your data first! It is easy to make an unrecoverable mistake.